# Python - Implement iteration over certain class attributes on given order

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield

I have a `Position` class, and it has two attributes, `Lat` and `Lon`.

I would like the following API by implementing `iterator` protocol (but some googling just confused me more):

```
pos = Position(30, 50)
print pos.Latitude
> 30

print pos.Longitude
> 50

for coord in pos:
    print coord
> 30
> 50

print list(pos)
> [30, 50]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define an [`__iter__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types):

```
class Position(object):
    def __init__(self, lat, lng):
        self.lat = lat
        self.lng = lng

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.lat
        yield self.lng

pos = Position(30, 50)
print(pos.lat)
# 30
print(pos.lng)
# 50
for coord in pos:
    print(coord)
# 30
# 50
print(list(pos))    
# [30, 50]
```

PS. [The PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends reserving capitalized names for classes. Following the conventional will help others understand your code more easily, so I've resisted the urge to use your attribute names, and have instead replaced them with `lat` and `lng`.

Comment: Perfect. As I suspected, it was simple, but I was sidetracked by `__iter__` returning `self`, thus requiring implementation of `__next__` method (unnecessary in this case). Also, this PEP you mention settles down a long time doubt I had. Lower-case attributes from now on, thank you twice!

Comment: (should point out that we can't use the name `long` as it would shadow the builtin `long`)